# Is Android studio a sufficient tool for making mobile games?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have been learning how to create apps in Android studio and was wondering if you can make whole games in it with advanced graphics or just the simple ones like 2048.

Comment: Yes you can, however you will need some extra tools also for sound and graphics. Game development is not only about code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use libgdx (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) and code game with Java or Kotlin in Android Studio (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle).

IMO, with libgdx it is harder to make 3D games than with Unity. But nothing is impossible. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a 2048 in Android, or brickbreaker, but for more complex and better looking games, you should look into Unity.
It is great for 2D and 3D, it's one of the favourites among mobile game developers, it's also cross platform

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html